# Jquery draggable not working properly in Chrome version (39.0.2171.95 m )

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

When button is clicked, pop up is opened. I am dragging that pop up to left , right, top and bottom . It is working fine in Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox. When i drag that pop up in chrome version (39.0.2171.95 m ),it is not working properly. It is moving here and there randomly.Please suggest me how to proceed further.

```
 $("#myModal").draggable({
          containment: "#container",
      handle: ".modal-header"
 });



<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" >
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="padding:0px 0px">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:12px;margin-right:12px;">&times;</button>
                                  <h3 class="popover-title">Voter Variables</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>${variableSubstitutionList}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @DelightedD0D : please have a look at it